# unable to refresh DOM element while heavy javascript calculation goes

Tags: javascript, dom, html, partial-page-refresh

I want to refresh a span element before my calculations start to inform user that calculation was started.

the following code never displays *'calculating'* message:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'calculating';
    for (var i=0; i<9999;i++){
        var y = Math.pow(i,i);
        console.log(y);
    }
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'done'; 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

how to fix that?

**Guys, setTimeout is not an option for me. besides it looks ugly.**

Comment: use `setTimeout()` a callback function which will gets called when your calculations will be done

Comment: Use a WebWorker, if you don't need to support old browsers. They're intended for heavy off-DOM processing such as this.

Comment: As suggested, put your heavy calculation inside timeout. This way you are allowing the browser to initiate additional thread where calculation will  be done while main thread will be handling the browser rendering etc.

Comment: @Goran.it No, JavaScript is single threaded. Always. It will just wait that time then insert that function into the call stack, but all on a single thread. while the function called by `setTimeout` is running, the browser will wait for it before running anything else.

Comment: @Utkanos, I think its too heavy to use this library for such small thing

Answer (score 0):

Place your code inside a `setTimeout()` call, and add a very minimal delay. I usually put 0ms, which just waits for the frame to render, then calls the function. Example:

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'calculating';
setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<9999;i++){
        var y = Math.pow(i,i);
        console.log(y);
    }
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'done'; 
}, 0);
```

The first argument is a function to be called after the time passes, the second argument is the time to wait before calling the function. Note that this may still hang the browser if the calculation is too big (e.g. 999999 loop steps on a 2.5GHz i5)

Comment: is it possible to avoid setTimeout ?